# what are the benefits of inserting the data into the database asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, database, asynchronous

I am learning a classical application called pet shop which uses .net technology.In order to deal with the order data,two solutions were provided by author of the application.One is insert the order data into the database synchronously，the other ，which is asynchronous ,put the order data into a message queue(MSMQ technology),then  using threads to receive the order data,finally,insert the data into database.The first solution is quite simple,the other is not,i want to know when asynchronous pattern is adopted,what benefits bring to the application?Performance or else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many *normal* programs do two things:

1. Interact with the user in a graphical user interface
2. Read and write data to from and to a database.

Often the database is on a remote server and the roundtrip times are significant (more than 200-500ms)

So one important goal in such a program is to keep the GUI responsive even if a database access is active. This is accomplished with asynchronous database access.

Please note: while an example with MSMQ and multithreading is good to learn things, something very similar is nowadays done with the `async/await` mechanism which is much simpler to use.

Comment: I understand what you mean，but i have another question，why should using MSMQ to cache the data？I can simply create a new thread to insert the data into database without msmq，in this way ui won`t be block

Comment: Well, if there are two threads, you have to transport the data form one thread to the other without blocking the first thread, so a shared region with locks won't do.

Comment: Transport the data from one thread to the other？why i need to do that？for example if i need to insert two orders，then i could create two thread two to finish the task，all the threads need to do is  such operation Order.add(OrderInfo) .this two threads have no relationship 。There is no transportation between them right？

Comment: Before you access your order from the other thread you have to lock() it. This will lock the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Async is used whenever more than one thing is trying to be completed at the same time.

In a basic service or possibly console application you might want to make a database, file or network operation and it is quite typically that your code must wait for the results of that before continuing. That is a clear synchronous program where async isn't going to improve anything and will likely add complexity at the cost of performance.

If on the other hand, you can process something else (perhaps a previous request result) whilst waiting for your new request to complete you can put that cpu to work during the downtime of making your request.

When dealing with UI, this is more commonly then first appears. Most native UI technologies will run code on the same thread as the one responsible for redrawing the UI. Meaning a button which when clicked, loads data from a database into the application synchronously will block the thread used to redraw the UI. You may see this in badly written software where the button staya pressed down.

Another pattern is parallel programming. Under the hood this many threads often doing the same logic but with different data. This can massively improve the speed at which data sets get processe but is a little off topic from your original question.

As a general rule, if it uses an external resource such as file, database or network, or if you simply expect execution time to be noticeable, make it async.